# Generalized Linear Model (GLM) in R

Tags: r, glm, gam

I have a response variable (A) which I transformed (logA) and predictor (B) from data (X) which are both continuous. How do I check the linearity between the two variables using Generalized Additive Model (GAM) in R. I use the following code

```
model <- gamlss(logA ~ pb(B) , data = X, trace = F)
```

but I am not sure about it, can I add `"family=Poisson"` in the code when logA is continuous in GLM? Any thoughts on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you are asking a statistical question. Better for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ , I try to answer your question below

Answer (score 0):

If your dependent variable is a count variable, you can use `family=PO()` without log transformation. With `family=PO()` a log link is already applied to transform the variable. See [help page for gamlss family](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gamlss.dist/versions/5.3-2/topics/gamlss.family) and also [vignette on count regression section 2.1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pscl/vignettes/countreg.pdf).

So it will go like:

```
library(gamlss)
fit = gamlss(gear ~ pb(mpg),data=mtcars,family=PO())
```

You can see that the predictions are log transformed and you need to take the exponential:

```
with(mtcars,plot(mpg,gear))
points(mtcars$mpg,exp(predict(fit,what="mu")),col="blue",pch=20)
```

[image]